# Creating an installer script

Tags: php, forms, post, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to create an installer, using a combination of fwrite and forms. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "db_config.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, "$host = " . $_POST['host'] . ";\n $username = " . $_POST['username'] . ";\n     $password = " . $_POST['password'] . ";\n $name = " . $_POST['name']";" ;);
fwrite($fh, 'mysql_connect("{$host}", "{$db_username}", "{$db_password}")\n or     die(mysql_error());\n mysql_select_db("{$db_name}")\n or die(mysql_error()); ?>' ;);
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

Here's the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home2/runetyco/public_html/ballpointradio/new/install_action.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `.`at the end of the line

```
[...]. $_POST['name'] . [<--] ";" ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

quite a few problems tbh.. sorted

```
<?php
$myFile = "db_config.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, '<?php' . PHP_EOL . '$host = "' . $_POST['host'] . '";' . PHP_EOL . '$username = "' . $_POST['username'] . '";' . PHP_EOL . '$password = "' . $_POST['password'] . '";' . PHP_EOL . '$name = "' . $_POST['name'] . '";' . PHP_EOL );
fwrite($fh, 'mysql_connect($host, $db_username, $db_password)' . PHP_EOL . 'or die(mysql_error());' . PHP_EOL . 'mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());' . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fh);
```

note: i wouldn't recommend doing it this way, typically much better to only write out a simple config file and keep all code static, but the above answers your question about the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

problem might be in `?>`. you'll have to escape it. also, you are not putting `<?php` in the beginning of your conf file.

why do you want it to be php file anyway. why not use ini file and [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), or xml maybe?

Comment: How does this look?.... <?php
$myFile = "db_config.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, "&lt;?php $host = " . $_POST['host'] . ";\n $username = " . $_POST['username'] . ";\n $password = " . $_POST['password'] . ";\n $name = " . $_POST['name'] . ";" );
fwrite($fh, 'mysql_connect("{$host}", "{$db_username}", "{$db_password}")\n or die(mysql_error());\n mysql_select_db("{$db_name}")\n or die(mysql_error()); ?&rt;' );
fclose($fh); 
?>

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's giving an error is because it's looking for the variable $host on line 4 - if you change the double quotes to single it should fix the problem - see below:

```
<?php
$myFile = "db_config.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, '$host = ' . $_POST['host'] . ';\n $username = ' . $_POST['username'] . ';\n $password = ' . $_POST['password'] . ';\n $name = ' . $_POST['name'] . ';\n\n';
fwrite($fh, 'mysql_connect("{$host}", "{$db_username}", "{$db_password}")\n or die(mysql_error());\n mysql_select_db("{$db_name}")\n or die(mysql_error()); ?>' ;);
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. You are however missing the closing `)` on line 4 ;)

Comment: if you take a look at what that will output, it'll have solid '\n' in the code, none of the variables will have quotes around them and a few other bits ;)

Comment: No, this wasn't the error, but I'm curious as to how this could work, because it would only grab '$host = host etc.'...